# Update 2nd level array in mongo using mongoose returns Unexpected token "."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have his model :

```
var field = {
    questionSets: [
        {
            name : "",
            questions: [
                {
                    question: {type: String, required: true},
                    answer: {type: String},
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this query :

```
SubjectiveForm.update(
     {_id:doc._id, questionSets.$._id:req.params.set_id},
     {$pushAll: {questions:req.body}},
     {upsert:true},
     function(err, questions){
        console.log("err", err);
        console.log("err", questions);
     }
)
```

But this line `{_id:doc._id, questionSets.$._id:req.params.set_id},` returns  `Unexpected token .` on `questionSets.$`.

BTW the `req.body` looks like this (a JSON) :

```
[
    {
         "question" : "Added 1?"
    },
    {
         "question" : "Added 2?"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

As `questionSets.$._id` is a key in JSON object you provided to update query, it should be `'questionSets.$._id'`(with quotes), it cant have a key including dots in it

```
SubjectiveForm.update(
     {_id:doc._id, 'questionSets.$._id':req.params.set_id},
     {$pushAll: {questions:req.body}},
     {upsert:true},
     function(err, questions){
        console.log("err", err);
        console.log("err", questions);
     }
)
```

Comment: WTF? Im so blind. >.< Thanks for this. Anyways the query above when performed returns `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }` it still doesn't update the document.

Comment: But the data is present :/

Comment: u can share the data from request and some documents?

Comment: Here's the request as well

route : `charting/questions/:questions_id/set/:set_id/add-new-question`

`localhost:3131/api/v0.1/charting/questions/56cff03e9ff240192da2fa34/set/56cff03e9ff240192da2fa35/add-new-question`

Comment: The following query should update the first set in array `questionSets` right?

Comment: what is `doc._id`, is it correct `56cff03e9ff240192da2fa34` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104613/discussion-between-naeem-shaikh-and-the-green-foxx).